# const timeoutError when try to connect to local mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

**this is my connection code from, w3schools**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

**
the below error shows when i run the code **

```
const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 116599938,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)     
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {        
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
  [cause]: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
      at connectionFailureError (D:\Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
    [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 27017
    }
  }
}

Node.js v18.14.2
```

when i changed localhost to 127.0.0.1  the error disappears but database created doesnt get printed in the terminal and also the code doesn't end

can any tell what is the reason and solution for this

Database created!

Comment: Can you share your `mongodb` package version?

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means nothing was listening on that port.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828293/2282634